# How do we calculate multiclass probabilities in yardstick?

Tags: r, tidymodels, yardstick

I have a multiclass classification problem and want to build a precision-recall curve using `pr_curve` from yardstick library in R. This function requires that a tibble with probabilities for each class were fed to it, like this (this is `data(hpc_cv)`).
[image]
How do I get there from my classification results, stored as columns in a tibble?

```
library(yardstick)
data <- tibble(predicted = as.factor(c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C")), 
               expected = as.factor(c("A", "B", "B", "C", "A", "C")))
data %>% conf_mat(truth = expected, estimate = predicted)
```

I have not found a function in yardstick (or elsewhere) to calculate those.

I am not sure how class probs are calculated, I am thinking along these lines:

```
data %>% filter(predicted == "A") %>% summarise(n = n() / 6)
```

Is this correct? If so, I wonder if there is a nice way to do it without for-loops on each class in each fold, and to receive a tibble like hpc_cv on the picture above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not sure how class probs are calculated

Class probabilities are generated by a specific model for each individual data point.

PR curves (and precision and recall) are metrics for data sets where the outcome has two classes. You can do [multiclass averaging](https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/articles/multiclass.html) to get an overall PR curve AUC though.

There is an example below but I would advise reading the [tidymodels book](https://www.tmwr.org) for a bit before proceeding.

```r
library(nnet) # <- for mutlinom_fit
library(tidymodels)

tidymodels_prefer()

data(hpc_data, package = "modeldata")

set.seed(1)
hpc_split <- initial_split(hpc_data)
hpc_train <- training(hpc_split)
hpc_test  <- testing(hpc_split)

set.seed(2)
mutlinom_fit <- 
  multinom_reg() %>% 
  fit(class ~ iterations + compounds, data = hpc_train)

test_predictions <- augment(mutlinom_fit, new_data = hpc_test)

# examples of the hard class predictions and the 
# predicted probabilities: 
test_predictions %>% select(starts_with(".pred")) %>% head()
#> # A tibble: 6 × 5
#>   .pred_class .pred_VF .pred_F .pred_M .pred_L
#>   <fct>          <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>
#> 1 VF             0.641   0.279  0.0670  0.0128
#> 2 VF             0.640   0.280  0.0671  0.0128
#> 3 VF             0.628   0.287  0.0711  0.0138
#> 4 VF             0.628   0.287  0.0711  0.0138
#> 5 VF             0.626   0.288  0.0716  0.0139
#> 6 VF             0.626   0.288  0.0719  0.0140

# a confusion matrix
test_predictions %>% conf_mat(class, .pred_class)
#>           Truth
#> Prediction  VF   F   M   L
#>         VF 516 278  74  16
#>         F   18  46  36   4
#>         M    2   7  19  21
#>         L    0  11   7  28

# create some metrics:
cls_metrics <- metric_set(accuracy, precision, recall, pr_auc)
# precision, recal, and the PR AUC are caluclated using macro weighting of 4 
# different 1 vs all results. 
# See https://yardstick.tidymodels.org/articles/multiclass.html

# evaluate them
test_predictions %>% 
  # See ?metric_set for more information. We pass the truth (class), all of the
  # predicted probability columns (.pred_VF:.pred_L), and the named hard class
  # predictions. 
  cls_metrics(class, .pred_VF:.pred_L, estimate = .pred_class)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 3
#>   .metric   .estimator .estimate
#>   <chr>     <chr>          <dbl>
#> 1 accuracy  multiclass     0.562
#> 2 precision macro          0.506
#> 3 recall    macro          0.411
#> 4 pr_auc    macro          0.481
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-09 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you. In my case, it is not a trained model, but a comparison of several distance metrics for text classification (like here https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-030-53360-1_3). I have a corpus of texts and a bunch of distance metrics (some of them implemented in philentropy), and I take multiple samples from my corpus to compare their performance. So, is it possible to get probs without training a model as in the example above?